# Objective C, NSXML parser delegate methods never get called

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

```
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser parse];
```

I have this in ApplicaitonDelegate.m file and I am trying to parse an xml document in - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. I am implement the NSXML delegate in my header file but the delegate method never gets called..

Comment: Can we see your implementation of your delegate method?

Comment: Yes, show us the method that you expect to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using NSASCIIStringEncoding.
Are you sure that your XML is ascii encoded ? 
If you don't know, try with NSUTF8StringEncoding. It's a better choice anyway because it "includes" ASCII.

Have you implemented the parseErrorOccurred delegate message ?

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
```

If there is an error related to encoding, you should get an error, e.g.

```
NSXMLParser error=31 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 31.)"
```